# Complex rolling scenario (CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY example)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I currently have data like the following (but bigger!)

```
/*--:::::::::::
DROP TABLE #target
DROP TABLE #Fact
*/--:::::::::::
CREATE TABLE #target 
    (
    PlayerKey INT,
    Name            VARCHAR(8),
    LiveKey     INT
    );
INSERT INTO #target 
    values
    (1,'michael',20130103),
    (2,'jackson',20130107);

CREATE TABLE #Fact 
    (
    DateKey     INT,
    PlayerKey INT,
    Amount      INT
    );
INSERT INTO #Fact 
    values
    (20130101,1,10),
    (20130102,1,90),
    (20130103,1,18),
    (20130103,2,79),
    (20130103,3,99),
    (20130104,2,15),
    (20130105,1,12),
    (20130105,2,15),
    (20130106,1,60),
    (20130107,1,96),
    (20130107,2,88),
    (20130107,4,28),
    (20130108,1,13),
    (20130108,2,15),
    (20130109,1,33),
    (20130109,2,67),
    (20130110,1,19),
    (20130110,2,17)
    ;
```

The start of the query is as follows.

```
DECLARE @NumDays INT = 3;

WITH    basic_cte AS
        (
        SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.Name ORDER BY f.DateKey),
                f.DateKey,
                d.Name,
                f.Amount
        FROM    #Fact f
                INNER JOIN #target d ON
                  f.PlayerKey = d.PlayerKey AND
                  f.DateKey >= d.LiveKey AND
                  f.DateKey < CONVERT(CHAR(8),CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),d.LiveKey,112))+@NumDays),112)
        )
SELECT  x.*,
        "RollingAmount" = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey)
FROM    basic_cte x;
```

This gives the following:

[image]

**Assuming that we have a `DimDate` production view available** how do I ensure that `michael` has a row for `20130104` with an amount of 0?

Also is it possible in the same script, to add new columns "AmountAll" and "AmountAllRolling" which would give numbers across all the players including PlayerKeys 3 and 4? I'm guessing this would involve changing the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

So given the above the final result would be as follows:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

via all the excellent help from Bogdan I've got the following.
I've added an extra total AmountGroup that is the total across the specified players - this was just "nice-to-have" and not part of the original specification.

```
DECLARE @NumDays INT = 3;

WITH    basic_cte AS
        (
        SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY x.DateKey),
                x.DateKey,
                d.Name,
                Amount      = ISNULL(f.Amount,0),
                AmountGroup = ISNULL(f.AmountGroup,0),
                AmountAll   = ISNULL(f.AmountAll,0)
        FROM    (
                SELECT  t.*, 
                EndLiveKey = CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR(8),CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),t.LiveKey,112))+@NumDays),112))
                FROM    #target t
                ) d 
                CROSS APPLY
                    (
                SELECT  dm.DateKey
                FROM    WHData.dbo.vw_DimDate dm
                WHERE   dm.DateKey >= d.LiveKey AND
                        dm.DateKey < d.EndLiveKey           
                ) x
                OUTER APPLY
                (
                SELECT  Amount  = SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerKey1 = PlayerKey2 THEN fbase.Amount END),
                        AmountGroup = SUM(CASE WHEN inGroup = 1 THEN fbase.Amount ELSE 0 END),
                        AmountAll   = SUM(fbase.Amount)
                FROM
                    (
                    SELECT  fct.Amount, 
                            fct.PlayerKey AS PlayerKey1, 
                        d.PlayerKey AS PlayerKey2,
                        CASE WHEN tt.PlayerKey IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS inGroup
                    FROM    #Fact fct 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN #target tt ON
                        fct.PlayerKey = tt.PlayerKey 
                    WHERE   fct.DateKey = x.DateKey
                ) fbase
            ) f
        )
SELECT   y.*,
        "RollingAmount"     = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey),
        "RollingAmountGroup"  = SUM(AmountGroup) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey),
        "RollingAmountAll"  = SUM(AmountAll) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey)
FROM    basic_cte y;
```

Comment: @down-voter please can you also mark to close the question so i know specifically what the problem is? Too specific?

Comment: *I didn't downvote* but I guess the reason was the datatype used for LiveKey and DateKey columns (INT instead of DATE: this means 4 bytes instead of 3 bytes and those conversions CONVERT(DATE,...) ).

Comment: @BogdanSahlean `DATE` is quite new - when our warehouse (which is star-schema and SSAS focussed) was first created only `DATETIME` was available so `INT` was smaller. Is it now standard practice to make datekeys type `DATE` formatted `YYYYMMDD`?

Comment: I repeat myself: 1) I didn't downvote. On the contrary: I upvoted this question because you provided DDL & DML statements for testing. I just guessed the reason for downvote. That's all. 2) Any [SMALL][DATE][TIME][2][OFFSET] value can be formatted using CONVERT/CAST or FORMAT(SQL20012+) or within report designer/client app.

Comment: In my opinion, the storage format (designated by datatype) and displayed format **are two different things** and (normally) displayed format (YYYYMMDD) shouldn't dictate the storage format (INT).

Comment: (I don't think you're the down-voter - the down-voter was here before but has deleted their comment ....which I criticised as they'd not read the question; they just deleted their comment, left, and I assume down-voted)

Comment: You should add also what do you need more from that query.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean the edit was so you can see the addition I made, and if you think it is wrong or could be done a lot more efficiently then you are free to edit.

Comment: What is the relationshiop between `#Fact` and `#target` ? 1 -> 0..1 , 1 -> n, n -> m , etc. ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean `#Fact` contains _all_ players ; whereas `#target` contains only a _small set_ of the players ...so I thought L.O.J was needed

Comment: If the "relationship" between `#fact` and `#target` rows is 1 row from `#fact` could have maximum 1 corresponding row in `#target` table then should be fine.

Comment: yes 1->0 or 1->1 : thanks I'll leave it as it is then with the L.O.J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have a DimDate table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE DimDate
(
DateKey INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

and `DateKey` column doesn't has gaps.

Solution:

```
DECLARE @NumDays INT = 3;

WITH    basic_cte AS
        (
            SELECT  x.DateKey,
                    d.Name,
                    Amount = ISNULL(f.Amount,0)
            FROM    
            (
                SELECT  t.*, CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR(8),CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),t.LiveKey,112))+@NumDays),112)) AS EndLiveKey
                FROM    #target t
            ) d 
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT  dm.DateKey
                FROM    DimDate dm
                WHERE   dm.DateKey >= d.LiveKey 
                AND     dm.DateKey < d.EndLiveKey           
            ) x
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #Fact f 
            ON f.PlayerKey = d.PlayerKey 
            AND f.DateKey = x.DateKey
        )
SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey),
        y.*,
        "RollingAmount" = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey)
FROM    basic_cte y;
```

**Edit #1:**

```
DECLARE @NumDays INT = 3;

WITH    basic_cte AS
        (
            SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY x.DateKey),
                    x.DateKey,
                    d.Name,
                    Amount      = ISNULL(f.Amount,0),
                    AmountAll   = ISNULL(fall.AmountAll,0)
            FROM    
            (
                SELECT  t.*, CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR(8),CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),t.LiveKey,112))+@NumDays),112)) AS EndLiveKey
                FROM    #target t
            ) d 
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT  dm.DateKey
                FROM    DimDate dm
                WHERE   dm.DateKey >= d.LiveKey 
                AND     dm.DateKey < d.EndLiveKey           
            ) x
            OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT  SUM(fct.Amount) AS Amount
                FROM    #Fact fct 
                WHERE   fct.DateKey = x.DateKey
                AND     fct.PlayerKey = d.PlayerKey
            ) f
            OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT  SUM(fct.Amount) AS AmountAll 
                FROM    #Fact fct 
                WHERE   fct.DateKey = x.DateKey
            ) fall
        )
SELECT  
        y.*,
        "RollingAmount"     = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey),
        "RollingAmountAll"  = SUM(AmountAll) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey)
FROM    basic_cte y;
```

**Edit #2:**

```
DECLARE @NumDays INT = 3;

WITH    basic_cte AS
        (
            SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY x.DateKey),
                    x.DateKey,
                    d.Name,
                    Amount      = ISNULL(f.Amount,0),
                    AmountAll   = ISNULL(f.AmountAll,0)
            FROM    
            (
                SELECT  t.*, EndLiveKey = CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR(8),CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),t.LiveKey,112))+@NumDays),112))
                FROM    #target t
            ) d 
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT  dm.DateKey
                FROM    DimDate dm
                WHERE   dm.DateKey >= d.LiveKey 
                AND     dm.DateKey < d.EndLiveKey           
            ) x
            OUTER APPLY
            (
                SELECT  AmountAll   = SUM(fbase.Amount),
                        Amount      = SUM(CASE WHEN PlayerKey1 = PlayerKey2 THEN fbase.Amount END)
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT  fct.Amount, fct.PlayerKey AS PlayerKey1, d.PlayerKey AS PlayerKey2
                    FROM    #Fact fct 
                    WHERE   fct.DateKey = x.DateKey
                ) fbase
            ) f
        )
SELECT  
        y.*,
        "RollingAmount"     = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey),
        "RollingAmountAll"  = SUM(AmountAll) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DateKey)
FROM    basic_cte y;
```

Comment: ...how easy do you think it will be to include the columns "AmountAll" and "AmountRollingAll"? Is it a case of building a new query?

Comment: See Edit 1. It's not the best solution, I know.

Comment: it's very quick when I use these `APPLY` scripts against our production tables (fact is nearly 1billion rows)! Your script takes about 3 seconds.

Comment: I tried to add another OUTER APPLY to create totals for just the specified players but it has really slowed it down - can I edit your question with my attempt (you can edit back!)

Comment: ok - will do. It'll probably be a relatively simple addition - I'm just not sure where!